# Stylesheet and JS linking error in WP multisite nested path

Tags: multisite

I have implementing the nested paths for WP multisite from the following tutorial: http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14052/wordpress-hacks-nested-paths-for-wpmu-blogs/

And almost 90% of the tasks are implemented but I need help with RewriteRule in .htaccess file.

Following is my current .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /james/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# uploaded files
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?files/(.+) wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I cant get the stylesheet, JS and images paths rewritten in the .htaccess, I have tried mutiple rules, i tried replacing:

```
RewriteRule  ^[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
```

with:

```
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)+(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
```

But this only helps get the images working for the default 2010 Theme for slider.

I am working on: WordPress version 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

WPMU was merged into WordPress back in ... 2010? I notice the tutorial you are looking at is from 2009.  I guess some people still confusingly refer to WPMU when instead it is WordPress Multisite.

While most of the concepts are probably still valid ... what are you trying to achieve?  Just to have separate domains with different themes is standard functionality without much effort.

If you want to setup WordPress Multisite with a number of domains, then you could try [WordPress MU Domain Mapping](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/).

It's this plugin that [Andrea_R is referring to in her comment](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/14052/wordpress-hacks-nested-paths-for-wpmu-blogs/comment-page-1/#comment-396236) on the tutorial you're trying to follow.

BTW - Andrea_R is one of the main moderators on the [WordPress Multisite Forum](http://wordpress.org/support/forum/multisite)    She even has a free guide on her website about how to setup a WordPress Network.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, yes i know the tutorial is pretty old but it still works and it is working 90% of the part.

I am trying to add nested paths when adding blog, which is working like "mydomain.com/department/travel" and it is adding and operating fine.

but the stylesheet, JS and images path are not working, something has to be with ReWrite rule

Comment: just not sure .. why do this when WPMU is no longer a separate code base and there are plugins that do this?

Comment: can u tell any plugin which lets u crete nested path blog?

Comment: Actually Andrea_R and her partner have a Network of Networks plugin ... see http://wpebooks.com/networks/